# pdfpages with alternate TOC entry

Tags: sectioning, captions, pdfpages

So what I'm trying to do is use the caption package with the pdfpages package so a alternate caption turns up in my toc. Sorry if the code didn't turn out perfect still new to posted on stack exchange. Using the page command in pdfpages lets me add a section but it does not allow me to change the caption. The reason I want to do this is to have a reference in my section in the part of the report but not to have the citation listed on the toc. Below is my attempt at a minimum working example. Outside the pdfpages I can just have `\section[Firmware]{Firmware \cite{firmware}}`, but this command string won't work in the `pdfpages` page command function.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{amsfonts}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage{caption}

\usepackage{refstyle}

\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\cleardoublepage

\tableofcontents

\newpage

\includepdf[pages=1,scale=.85,, pagecommand=\section{ Firmware \cite{firmware}} ]{firmware.pdf}

\includepdf[pages=2-,scale=.85,pagecommand={}]{firmware.pdf}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
pagecommand={\section[Firmware]{ Firmware \cite{firmware}}}
```

to get

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\cleardoublepage

\includepdf[pages=1,scale=.85,, pagecommand={\section[Firmware]{ Firmware \cite{firmware}}} ]{pgfmanual}

\includepdf[pages=2-3,scale=.85,pagecommand={}]{pgfmanual}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ran into another issue with labelling but solved it by putting the /label command after the /section. I swear I was trying the exact thing you described but maybe I was missing braces. Anyways, much appreciated.

Comment: @tangosierra Braces are badly needed here and yes, always put label after the section.